# How to effectively simulate high density systems in GROMACS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs, polymers

[image: With solute] [image: Pure solvent]

I have a system with a dense liquid solvent and a polymer solute. I have inserted all the molecules randomly using `gmx insert-molecules` and then did the energy minimization and equilibration steps to get to the required density.  However as the solvent is so dense, there's no space for the movement of the polymer molecules over the course of the production simulation run. I have waited for upto 10ns but there barely seems to be a change. Is there a way to build such systems to observe change in properties with and without the solute in shorter periods of time? Should I consider smaller densities of solvent or higher concentrations of solute? If so, what is the criteria to match the properties like viscosity from the simulation with that of experimental properties that are performed at high densities and low concentrations of solute?

Comment: Can you give us a temperature/image of a model?  It may just be that your system is so viscous that nothing will happen over long periods of time.

Comment: @TristanMaxson When experiments are performed on the same system at the same temperature of 298K and 350 bar, the viscosity improved significantly. But, it is not seen that way with this simulation. Added the images for reference.

Comment: Have you considered metadynamics?

Comment: Maybe increasing the solvent density in small steps can give you a clue about what is happening.

Comment: KavyaMrudula: Have you had a chance to consider the suggestion by Camps? @MDSimulation Perhaps the user doesn't know what Metadynamics is. Perhaps you can could elaborate on why metadynamics would help?

Comment: Were these suggestions helpful or did you run into any further issues while applying them?

Comment: @MD Simulation Thanks but I do not know what metadynamics is. Can you please point me towards a source as to how I can understand metadynamics in these systems?

Comment: @Camps  Increasing pressure in small steps did seem to work for the movement initially. And another step I figured out recently was running the system in NVE after the whole series of simulations of getting it to the required pressure. That seemed to working. The whole of solvent molecules clustered around the solute and vacuum seems to have come up inside the box. What does the result with part vacuum inside the simulation box mean?

Comment: @Nike Sorry, took me long enough to respond.

Comment: @Camps , Kavya, do you think it would be appropriate for us to add the implicit-solvent tag or the explicit-solvent tag?